# Get property from JSON response in Cypress

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, response, cypress

Can someone, help in solve asserting following response:

```
{"rowId":"899103a2-a9b1-42t3-bc3w-6we638a43fc3","polygons":[{"polygon1":"40eea45f-ffc8-46vb-9ae6-26f5ba5edf4b","polygon2":{"type":"Polygon","geoId":[[[-45.428529,48.321791],[-45.428529,48.321791],[-45.428529,48.321791],[-45.428148,48.321653],[-45.428164,48.32163],[-45.428529,48.321791]]]}}]}
```

Tried with following code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('updateResponse', (request, elementCss) => {
cy.intercept(request, '**/api/rows*').as('update')
cy.xpath(elementCss)
.click()
.wait('@update', { timeout: 20000 })
.then((xhr) => {
  cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body))
    .its('response.statusCode')
    .should('eq', 200)
    .its('rowId')
    .should('not.be.empty')
 })
})
```

where **request** variable is **POST** request.

Achieved only to assert that response code is **200**. For second assert, **rowID** is not empty, I got error:

```
"*Timed out retrying after 10000ms: cy.its() errored because the property: rowId does not exist on your subject.*"
```

I want ta assert, also, that **polygon2** array is not empty and having data inside **geoId**.

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("updateResponse", (request, elementCss) => {
  cy.intercept(request, "**/api/rows*").as("update")
  cy.xpath(elementCss)
    .click()
    .wait("@update", { timeout: 20000 })
    .then((xhr) => {
      expect(xhr.status).to.eq(200)
      expect(xhr.body).to.have.property(
        "rowId",
        "899103a2-a9b1-42t3-bc3w-6we638a43fc3"
      )
      expect(xhr.body.rowId).not.to.be.empty
    })
})
```

Or, in your case instead of just `rowId` you have to provide `response.body.rowId`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("updateResponse", (request, elementCss) => {
  cy.intercept(request, "**/api/rows*").as("update")
  cy.xpath(elementCss)
    .click()
    .wait("@update", { timeout: 20000 })
    .then((response) => {
      cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))
        .its("response.statusCode")
        .should("eq", 200)
        .its("response.body.rowId")
        .should("not.be.empty")
    })
})
```

Comment: Tried both proposed solution, unfortunately, neither works. Here is log from second proposed solution:

"Timed out retrying after 10000ms: cy.its() errored because the property: response does not exist on your subject."

Comment: Are you sure `rowId` is present in the response json and if its present is it accessible by `response.body.rowId`, and there is no branching in between?

Comment: Sorry, first solution does work. My mistake, incorrectly implemented
Thank you @Alapan Das